# Discord.js Get the member in a guild by username

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I was trying to get all the member's usernames on my discord server 
However, it just gave back 8-9/25 members including 6 BOTs

Here is my code

```
const list = client.guilds.cache.get(msg.guildId); 
list.members.cache.each(r => {
   console.log(r.user.username)
})
```

Besides that, I have also tried these ways

```
const list = client.guilds.cache.get(msg.guildId); 
   list.members.cache.array().forEach(r => {
      console.log(r.user.username)
})
```

```
const user = client.users.cache.find(u => u.username == '//The Given username')
```

```
const user = msg.guild.roles.cache.get('//The Main Role in my Server')
             .members.map(m => m.user.username == '//The given username')
```

```
let user = client.users.cache.get('username', '//The given username');
```

But sometimes it just returned my and my BOT's username or undefined.

I'm trying to get all the members on the server and from that, I can find out the user has the same username with the given username, not tags or IDs

I have turned on the [Gateway Intents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POhGl.png) but it didn't help

Please help with my project, I really need all the suggestions from you

Comment: So, are you trying to get all guild users' usernames or specific user by their username?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch) to cache all members, and return them. Make sure you have `GUILD_MEMBERS` intent:

```js
list.members.fetch().then(m => {
  let members = m.map(u => u.user.username)
  console.log(members) //array of all members
  //you can also use "m.each(u => console.log(u.user.username))" to log each one individually
})
```

Or use `async-await`

```js
const m = await list.members.fetch()
let members = m.map(u => u.user.username)
console.log(members)
```

Comment: after I remove .cache, it works!! Thanks a lot